# Showing only one row of items with css independently of users resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a couple of elements inside a container

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Nr of items can differ because those items are generated dynamically from a database.

Is there any easy way of showing items that only show on **ONE row** independtly of what screen resolution user has (with **css**?) ?  Or is **Javascript** the only way to achieve this?  (I'm thinking you would have to calculate current width of the images and tell how many would fit one row and based on that make adjustments but hoping there are are a better solution out there)

the **css** looks something like this:

```
.item {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    width:19%;   
    margin-right:1%;
}

.item img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I'll try to clarify my issue.

Lets say for a example a user has a resolution of 1280x1024. Then about 5 items would fit one row and maybe 2 on next row. I only want to display the 5 first items.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 1 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 2 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 3 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 4 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 5 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- hide 6 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- hide 7 -->
</div>
```

Example 2:
If user has screen resolution 800x600 (yeah sure, but just for the sake of clarification!) then maybe three items would fit on one row, then I only want to show those three items.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 1 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 2 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- show 3 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- hide 4 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- hide 5 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- hide 6 -->
    <div class="item"><img src="blabla.png" /></div> <!-- hide 7 -->
</div>
```

Comment: See how different the 2 answers you have are? Your question is not clear enough. What I understand : You only want one item per line, on any screen size?

Comment: I've tried to clarify my issue now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is `CSS` only solution

```
.container

    {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would work? That just hides when excedding to right right of the element. If I set height to a specific hight (the height of the item) then it would work, but then the height would have to be calculated with js (because the heights can vary based on users resolution)?

Comment: This got me going in right direction. Of couse the solution is so simple. I just have to combine this with media queires and set height of the items based on users resolution. I'll accept this an answer even though I really appreiciate your other answers (I would like to accept several answers here but it's not possible).

Answer (score 2):

**Try this** - Use [display:table-cell and display:table](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

- `display:table`  **The element behave like a `<table>` element**
- `display:table-cell` **The element behave like a `<td>` element**

**[See the working Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/4onep9wq/)**

```
.item {
    width:auto;   
    margin-right:1%;
     display: table-cell;
}
.container

    {
    display: table;

    }
.item img {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - Checkout the working demo

Comment: It would be better to set the image width as `max-width:100%` and the height to `auto` to avoid distortion - http://jsfiddle.net/hm5cnLmx/1/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I've clarified my issue. Please read. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make CSS Media Queries.

With this code the user needs to have at least `480px` to view the class `item`, you can also you `min-width`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.item{
visibility: hidden;
}
```